# How to put vertical dashed gridlines on Highcharts heatmap

Tags: asp.net-core, highcharts, heatmap, gridlines

I'm plotting a HighCharts heatmap of a wafer with around 50~70k points (it's like a CPU/processor silicon wafer). I need to put horizontal and vertical gridlines visible on the map, so that our engineers can easily figure out what's going on with the actual unit.

I have two concerns:

1. Horizontal gridlines are already OK, but the vertical gridlines are not drawn or visible. I thought, I just need to set gridZIndex=4. Kindly see image below - it should be drawn based on xAxis.tickPositions values (similar to yAxis)

   [image: Wafer map actual result vs desired output]
2. I put some color options I found, but none of them could change the grid's color.

So far this is my code:

```
var option = {

    chart: {
        type: 'heatmap',
        zoomType: 'xy',
    },

    boost: {
        useGPUTranslations: true
    },

    title: {
        text: chrt_title,
        align: 'left',
        x: 0,
        style: {
            fontSize: '12px',
        }
    },

    exporting: {
        buttons: {
            contextButton: {
                menuItems: [
                    'viewFullscreen', 'downloadPNG', 'downloadXLS'
                ]
            }
        },
        enable: true,
    },

    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        tickPositions: [1, 19, 43, 67, 91, 115, 139, 163, 183],
        gridZIndex: 4,             //  DOESN'T WORK
        gridLineDashStyle: 'Dash',
        gridLineWidth: 1,          // DOESN'T WORK
        lineColor: 'red',
        minorTickColor: 'red',
        tickColor: 'red'
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        reversed: true,
        labels: {
            enabled: false,
        },

        tickPositions: [1, 82, 116, 174, 272, 370, 428, 462, 544]
        gridZIndex: 4,             // ONLY PUT THIS AND WORKS ALREADY
        gridLineDashStyle: 'Dash', // THIS WORKS TOO (Dot,Solid,etc)
        lineColor: 'red',          
        minorTickColor: 'red',
        tickColor: 'red'
    },

    colorAxis: {
        stops: colrstops,
        min: minval,
        max: maxval,
        startOnTick: true,
        endOnTick: true,
        labels: {
            format: '{value}',
            style: {
                fontSize: '8px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        boostThreshold: 100,
        borderWidth: 0,
        nullColor: '#ffffff',
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: chrt_title + '<br/>',
            pointFormat: 'RB{point.y} SL{point.x} <b>{point.value}</b>'
        },
        turboThreshold: Number.MAX_VALUE, // #3404, remove after 4.0.5 release
        data: data
    }]
}
```

As you can see, both xAxis and yAxis have gridZIndex = 4, gridLineDashStyle = 'Dash', but only the yAxis that gives the horizontal gridlines, no luck for xAxis (assuming this is where  need to set the vertical gridlines) :(

the only similar question i found reg vertical gridlines is this one:
[Highcharts: xAxis with vertical gridlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39509044/highcharts-xaxis-with-vertical-gridlines)
but I tried to put the gridLineWidth=1, still nothin's happening T-T please help. thanks very much.

---

**Update:**
I temporarily replaced my option{} based on @ppotaczek sample but vertical gridlines still did not appeared.

Then I played with my own option{}, tried to add min and max in xAxis, and tried to temporarily removed my dynamic data and use @ppotaczek sample, the layout remains the same (no vertical gridlines)..

Also thought it has something to do with the version i'm using..? it's 9.0.1 - so I tried to update to latest 9.1.1, but also have same result.

[image: @ppotaczek]

```
var option = {
    chart: {
        type: 'heatmap',
    },

    xAxis: {
        tickPositions: [1, 19, 43, 67, 91, 115, 139, 163, 183],
        min: 1,
        max: 183,
        gridZIndex: 4,              //  DOESN'T WORK
        gridLineDashStyle: 'Dash',
        gridLineWidth: 1,           // DOESN'T WORK
        lineColor: 'red',
        minorTickColor: 'red',
        tickColor: 'red'
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        reversed: true,
        labels: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        tickPositions: [1, 82, 116, 174, 272, 370, 428, 462, 544],
        gridLineDashStyle: 'Dash',  // THIS WORKS TOO (Dot,Solid,etc)
        lineColor: 'red',
        minorTickColor: 'red',
        tickColor: 'red',
    },

    colorAxis: {},

    series: [{
        data: [
            [10, 0, 1],
            [20, 1, 5],
            [30, 1, 5],
        ],
        
    }]
}
```

Comment: Hi @K4L37, There is probably some problem with data. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j65rpfsm/ - vertical grid lines are visible if you define `min` and `max` for x-axis.

Comment: hi @ppotaczek, thanks.. i temporarily replaced my option{} and put what you have in jsfiddle but vertical gridlines still did not appeared.

then i played with my own option{}, tried to add min and max in xAxis, and i tried to temporarily removed my dynamic data and use your sample, the layout remain the same (no vertical gridlines).. 

also thought it has something to do with the version i'm using..? it's 9.0.1 - so i tried to update to latest 9.1.1, but also have same result.

Comment: Could you reproduce the issue in jsfiddle?